# How to find a grep-ed value in log files in a directory every 60 minutes in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, bin

I have a directory called /qfs/input/ad_logs. Every 15 minutes or so, a new file is dumped into this directory. I need to check this directory every hour to see if a certain value in the 10th field of the logs. Have been using the command `lzop -cd file_name_20200209.lzo | cut -f10 -d, | grep mcid=` to find the value in the logs.

How do I do this shell script to automate the process and alert me of the found value in the logs?

Comment: Instead of checking on a timer, I would suggest using a tool like [`incron`](https://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=doc&lang=en) that can trigger your code to run the moment any new file is closed after having been written to.

Answer (score 2):

Create a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
if lzop -cd file_name_20200209.lzo | cut -f10 -d, | grep -q mcid=; then
      # alert me of the found value in the logs?
      logger -p local3.info -t "VERY_IMPORTANT_SCRIPT" "alert! The value was found in the logs"
fi
```

Then add this script to [cron](https://www.google.com/search?q=cron+how+to+add+script) if you have it or create a [system timer service](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+create+systemd+timer+service) if you system uses systemd that will run your script each one hour. For example create two files:

```
# /etc/systemd/service/very_important_script.timer
[Unit]
Description=Run very_important_script hourly

[Timer]
OnCalendar=hourly
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

and

```
# /etc/systemd/service/very_important_script.service
[Unit]
Description=very_important_script 

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/the/very_important_script

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and execute `systemctl deamon-refresh ; systemctl enable very_important_script.timer ; systemctl start very_important_script.timer` to start the timer.

You could for example take into account only files changed in the last hour:

```
#!/bin/sh
if 
      find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'file_name_*.lzo' -mmin -60 |
      xargs lzip -cd | 
      cut -f10 -d, | grep -q mcid=  
      # maybe add -m1 to grep?
then
      # alert me of the found value in the logs?
      logger -p local3.info -t "VERY_IMPORTANT_SCRIPT" "alert! The value was found in the logs"
fi
```

Comment: thank you for this. I am confused on how the script will account for all files in the directory. As I mentioned the files are coming through every 15 mins or so but I only care to check the logs every hour which is set in the cron job. I have been using ```lzop -cd file_name_202002*.lzo | cut -f10 -d, | grep -q mcid=``` with the * to go through all the different log files. Can I do this in this script or do I need to make a loop function? Very new to bash/linux

Comment: Och it willl not, I tought that the filename will stay the same. Sure, just use `file_name_202002*.lzo`. You could also use like `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'file_name_*.lzo' -mmin -60 | xargs lzip -cd` for example to only decompress files changed in less then an hour ago.